# OutOfMemoryException in Sharp Develop 4.2

Tags: c#, debugging, memory, sharpdevelop

I have a C# programmed application and after about 13 days of running with the debugger of sharp develop 4.2.1,the application throws an OutOfMemoryException.

I am confused because of the fact that the exception stack trace comes from sharp develop. Is this a problem or just misleading ?

I had also out of memory exceptions in the past but everytime the stack trace was shown some code of my project and not from sharp develop. I fixed these issues by using the ANTS memory profiler.

Do you have some ideas ?
For longer time of running the application, is the "release" build without debugger running more stable ?

Many thanks in advance.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
Complete Stacktrace:

SharpDevelop Version : 4.2.1.8805-9345aa7c

.NET Version         : 4.0.30319.1

OS Version           : Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1

Current culture      : Japanese (Japan) (ja-JP)

Current UI language  : en

Working Set Memory   : 1017236kb

GC Heap Memory       : 713962kb


Exception thrown:

System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32 value)

   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.EnsureCapacity(Int32 min)

   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)

   at Debugger.Interop.TrackedComObjects.Track(Object obj)

   at Debugger.Interop.TrackedComObjects.ProcessOutParameter(Object parameter)

   at Debugger.ManagedCallbackSwitch.GetProcessCallbackInterface(String name, ICorDebugAppDomain pAppDomain)

   at Debugger.ManagedCallbackProxy.<>c__DisplayClass58.<Exception>b__57()

   at Debugger.MTA2STA.<>c__DisplayClass4.<EnqueueCall>b__1()

   at Debugger.MTA2STA.PerformCall()

   at Debugger.MTA2STA.PerformAllCalls()

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()


---- Recent log messages:

09:37:15.383 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception

09:37:15.383 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Process has queued callbacks

09:37:15.384 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception2 (type=DEBUG_EXCEPTION_FIRST_CHANCE)

09:37:15.391 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception2 (type=DEBUG_EXCEPTION_USER_FIRST_CHANCE)

09:37:15.391 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Process has queued callbacks

09:37:15.391 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception2 (type=DEBUG_EXCEPTION_USER_FIRST_CHANCE)

09:37:15.392 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Process has queued callbacks

09:37:15.392 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception2 (type=DEBUG_EXCEPTION_USER_FIRST_CHANCE)

09:37:15.396 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception2 (type=DEBUG_EXCEPTION_USER_FIRST_CHANCE)

09:37:15.397 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception2 (type=DEBUG_EXCEPTION_CATCH_HANDLER_FOUND)

09:37:15.397 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Process has queued callbacks

09:37:15.398 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception2 (type=DEBUG_EXCEPTION_CATCH_HANDLER_FOUND)

09:37:15.398 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Process has queued callbacks

09:37:15.399 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception2 (type=DEBUG_EXCEPTION_CATCH_HANDLER_FOUND)

09:37:15.403 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception2 (type=DEBUG_EXCEPTION_CATCH_HANDLER_FOUND)

09:37:15.405 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception

09:37:15.405 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Process has queued callbacks

09:37:15.407 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception2 (type=DEBUG_EXCEPTION_FIRST_CHANCE)

09:37:15.410 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception

09:37:15.410 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Process has queued callbacks

09:37:15.411 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception2 (type=DEBUG_EXCEPTION_FIRST_CHANCE)

09:37:15.411 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Process has queued callbacks

09:37:15.411 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Callback: Exception

09:37:15.411 [1] DEBUG - Debugger: Process has queued callbacks

09:38:13.301 [1] ERROR - ThreadException caught

--> Exception:

System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32 value)

   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.EnsureCapacity(Int32 min)

   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)

   at Debugger.Interop.TrackedComObjects.Track(Object obj)

   at Debugger.Interop.TrackedComObjects.ProcessOutParameter(Object parameter)

   at Debugger.ManagedCallbackSwitch.GetProcessCallbackInterface(String name, ICorDebugAppDomain 
pAppDomain)

   at Debugger.ManagedCallbackProxy.<>c__DisplayClass58.<Exception>b__57()

   at Debugger.MTA2STA.<>c__DisplayClass4.<EnqueueCall>b__1()

   at Debugger.MTA2STA.PerformCall()

   at Debugger.MTA2STA.PerformAllCalls()

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, 
CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, 
ContextCallback callback, Object state)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback 
callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback 
callback, Object state)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()



---- Post-error application state information:

Installed 3rd party AddIns: 

Workbench.ActiveContent: <null>
```

Comment: Well, the fact that it crashes in library code does not mean that it is not your code that uses to much memory. If you've used MemoryProfiler, you'll be able to see what objects use the memory when the crash happens.

Comment: Try to make sure you are calling the Dispose method of every IDisposable object.

Comment: Why is your programm running 13 days from the IDE? Is this a Test? Make a Release-Build and let these build run 13 days. And what is your programm doing 13 days long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a memory leak in SharpDevelop's debugger. It maintains a list of any COM objects it uses, and doesn't release them until the end of the debugging session.

If you need to run your program over long periods of time, you should run it without debugger. If necessary, you can later still attach the debugger to the process.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will try it again without debugger and accept this as an answer if it was the root cause.